# Why can't I update nix?

Tags: nix, nixos

I'm using nixos on wsl.

According to this [link](https://nix.dev/tutorials/install-nix#verify-installation)

```
nix --version
```

shoud return 2.11.0 . On my computer this is 2.8.1 Therefore I don't have the last nix version.

I've fast followed this [procedure](https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/installation/upgrading.html). I've only changed nixpkg with nixos because I'm on nixos (as the documentation say)

```
nix-channel --update;
nix-env -iA nixos.nix nixos.cacert;
```

First  try:

```
nix --version
```

> 2.8

I continue as if I had more than one user

```
systemctl daemon-reload; 
systemctl restart nix-daemon

nix --version
```

> 2.8

Why I don't have the right version

Comment: If you're staying on the 22.05 channel then 2.8 _is_ the right version. You need to switch channels (to either 22.11 or unstable) to get anything newer. Arguably this is more of a "using your Linux distro" question than a nix-the-language question, and less topical here than it would be at [UNIX.se].

Comment: (the link you post is for verifying a _new_ install, which will be on 22.11 by default; older installs follow older channels)